# Resize the .resize class dependant on screen size

Tags: jquery, screen-size

I have the code that works at current

```
jQuery.event.add(window, "load", resizeFrame);
jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resizeFrame);

function resizeFrame() 
{
var w = $(window).width();
$('.resize').css('width', (w <= 1680) ? 1680 : 1920);
}
```

but now i need to add in other screen sizes, such as:

```
$('.resize').css('width', (w <= 1280) ? 1280 : 1920);
$('.resize').css('width', (w <= 1024) ? 1024 : 1920);
```

but im unsure about how to chain these together, ive tried using || but this didn't work

help appreciated

Comment: Would [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) help? See also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: Also, why are you using `jQuery.event.add()` instead of `jQuery.bind()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function resizeFrame() {
  var height = $(window).height(),
      width  = $(window).width(),
      resizeWidth;

  if (width <= 1024) {
    resizeWidth = 1024;
  } else if (width <= 1280) {
    resizeWidth = 1280;
  } else if (width <= 1680) {
    resizeWidth = 1680;
  } else {
    resizeWidth = 1920;
  }

  $('.resize').css('width', resizeWidth);
}
```

Comment: You have the values backwards, I believe; the smallest should be at the top, then get bigger.

Comment: Only other quibble I have is that the `$(window).height()` is not used.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.resize').css('width', function() {
  var width = 1920;
  if(w <= 1680 && w > 1280) {
    width = 1680;
  } else if(w <= 1280 && w > 1024) {
     width = 1280;
  } else if(w <= 1024) {
     width = 1024;
  }
  return width;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not as readable as an if/else, but you can stick one ternary inside another, and do this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var w = $(this).width(),
        width = w <= 1024 ? 1024 : w <= 1280 ? 1280 : w <= 1680 ? 1680 : 1920;
    $('.resize').css('width', width);
}
```